# How to auto scroll to target div with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

If I have a structure like:

```
<div id="listofstuff">
<div class="anitem">
   <span class="itemname">Item1</span>
   <span class="itemdescruption">AboutItem1</span>
</div>
<div class="anitem">
   <span class="itemname">Item2</span>
   <span class="itemdescruption">AboutItem2</span>
</div>
<div class="anitem">
   <span class="itemname">Item3</span>
   <span class="itemdescruption">AboutItem3</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Say I continue this pattern until item5... and I wanted to make it so that when the page loads, it would search for the div with itemname "Item5", and scroll to it so that it is visible. Assume that the listofstuffdiv is sized small such that only 3 anitems are shown at any given time, but since overflow:auto exists, user can scroll.

I want to make it so that jquery can scroll to the item it found so it is visible without the user having to scroll down to item5;.

Comment: FYI you have loose `</h3>` in your markup

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/uaewc/2/

You don't need the scrollTo plugin for this..

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    lastElementTop = $('#listofstuff .anitem:last-child').position().top ;
    scrollAmount = lastElementTop - 200 ;

$('#listofstuff').animate({scrollTop: scrollAmount},1000);
});
```

CSS

```
.anitem {
height:100px;
}

#listofstuff {

height:300px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

---

**with a little more action and variables**   http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/uaewc/5/

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var wrapper = $('#listofstuff'),
    element = wrapper.find('.anitem'),
    lastElement = wrapper.find('.anitem:last-child'),
    lastElementTop = lastElement.position().top,
    elementsHeight = element.outerHeight(),
    scrollAmount = lastElementTop - 2 * elementsHeight;

    $('#listofstuff').animate({
        scrollTop: scrollAmount
    }, 1000, function() {
        lastElement.addClass('current-last');
    });
});
```

Comment: just updated my answer.. The scroll was too much.. the height of two divs above should be subtracted (e.g. 200 for this example)

Comment: Now, your code became a little more complex, maybe it's not necessary to reinvent the wheel, and to use a plugin (2.5k for ScrollTo) ;) A renowned plugin is approved by a lot of people, tested with all browsers, etc.

Comment: I use the scrollTo plugin a lot. but if this is needed for a static set of elements my first version is probably a lot more lightweight. If this needs to be dynamic, I would probably also use the scrollTo plugin. Even my second version (which is partially dynamic) is a lot lighter. This came in handy for me quite a few times.

Comment: I am having problems since the .anitems are being dynamically generated after the user clicks on a button.

Comment: @Teiviere. what do you mean by dynamically created? provide a fiddle if possible. dynmically created or with dynmic height? both? if the elements are created dynamically, the function should be run AFTER the elements are fully loaded. How are the elements created.. (best solution is to add a fiddle to show it)

Comment: I am getting a: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null. The elements are being created through $.ajax where $('#thelist').append(the anitem); is being called multiple times. I currently have a method makeTheAnItems(); with the scrollToBottommostItem(); right after.

Comment: @Teiviere  sorry had a mistake try this one... http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/uaewc/7/

Comment: if you use ajax to create the elements you should animate AFTER Ajax  "complete"

Comment: That worked perfectly. Out of curiosity, is it possible instead of going down to the last one, to find the anitem with the name say "theitemname"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a plugin like [ScrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

And call `$.scrollTo` with a selector when the page is loaded :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.scrollTo( $('#listofstuff .aniItem:eq(4)'), 500); // index start with 0
});
```