# how to automatically scroll down a html page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, height

I'm trying to start each page after the homepage about 500px down, similar to this website: http://unionstationdenver.com/

You'll notice when viewing pages after the homepage, you're automatically scrolled down without notice but you can than scroll up to revel the featured slider again.

I've played with scrolledHeight but I dont think that is what I need????

Basically I have a featured section that is on top of all my content pages, but you shouldn't be able to see this section until you scroll up. Any help?

Comment: you might want to look at this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773405/how-to-auto-scroll-to-target-div-with-jquery/8773563#8773563

Comment: Sweet! My only concern is that you still see the animation of the scroll. So each page I click on will load the first 500px and than scroll me to the content beneath it. That will get annoying to the user. Thoughts?

Answer (score 53):

You can use `.scrollIntoView()` for this. It will bring a specific element into the viewport.

Example:

```
document.getElementById( 'bottom' ).scrollIntoView();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/DG8yR/

Script:

```js
function top() {
    document.getElementById( 'top' ).scrollIntoView();    
};

function bottom() {
    document.getElementById( 'bottom' ).scrollIntoView();
    window.setTimeout( function () { top(); }, 2000 );
};

bottom();
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="top">top</div>
<div id="bottom">bottom</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#top {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 3000px;
}

#bottom {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: This solution works for me under IE but not Chrome.  Any ideas?

Comment: More info: it works in Chrome on the first page load but not on refresh. I think it's due to this bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=280460. If I hard-refresh the page it works, i.e. clicking in the URL bar and hitting enter.  But soft-resets like the page refreshing or clicking the refresh button (or hitting F5) do not work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use two different techniques to achieve this.

The first one is with javascript: set the scrollTop property of the scrollable element (e.g. `document.body.scrollTop = 1000;`).

The second is setting the link to point to a specific id in the page e.g.

```
<a href="mypage.html#sectionOne">section one</a>
```

Then if in your target page you'll have that ID the page will be scrolled automatically.

Comment: For your first technique, how do you get it so it's down to the position of a specific element?

Comment: Yes I have that about doing anchors but that is the last resort. I just can't tell how these guys did it http://unionstationdenver.com/

Comment: @Wex in plain javascript you can find the position of an element inside a document like this: `var topPosition = document.getElementById("myElement").offsetTop;`

Comment: @Hambone you can see in this script [link](http://unionstationdenver.com/lib/js/550.js) that they are using the scrollTo method of the window object. More info: [scrollTo on mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.scrollTo)

Answer (score 3):

here is the example using Pure JavaScript

```js
function scrollpage() {  
 function f() 
 {
  window.scrollTo(0,i);
  if(status==0) {
      i=i+40;
   if(i>=Height){ status=1; } 
  } else {
   i=i-40;
   if(i<=1){ status=0; }  // if you don't want continue scroll then remove this line
  }
 setTimeout( f, 0.01 );
 }f();
}
var Height=document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
var i=1,j=Height,status=0;
scrollpage();
</script>
```

```css
<style type="text/css">

 #top { border: 1px solid black;  height: 20000px; }
 #bottom { border: 1px solid red; }

</style>
```

```html
<div id="top">top</div>
<div id="bottom">bottom</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `document.scrollTop` to change the position of the document. Set the `scrollTop` of the `document` equal to the `bottom` of the featured section of your site

Comment: scrollTop is applicable just to a DOM element, not to the document

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.scrollTop = 99999999;</script>';
        ob_flush();
        ob_end_flush();
        flush();
        ob_start();
?>
```

does the trick for me.