# Refreshing view after changing $scope data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, mean-stack

I know there are some similar questions, but I haven't had success with any of the answers, none of the situations seem exactly similar. I am quite new to Angular and I know the whole process here isn't optimal but I feel like I'm close to getting at least a working prototype to refine:

I am trying to create an app that executes scripts on a schedule on the server, so in the background we have the following code which sends a request to run all of the files scheduled to run every 5 seconds. The scripts execute and a mongo database is updated - each "test" has an array of "results". Each time the script is executed, a new "result" is created and pushed to test.results array.

```
var interval  = 5000;
setInterval(function() {
 request.get(
    'http://localhost:3000/tests/run/5000',
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) { return next(err) }
    }
);
}, interval);
```

On the Angular side, there is a page that displays all of the results in test.results. When the page first loads, it looks up the current test and we have it as state param:

```
// The apps state, displays the selected "test", and lists results for the test.
      .state('tests', {
        url: '/tests/{id}',
        templateUrl: '/tests.html',
        controller: 'TestsCtrl',
        resolve: {
          test: ['$stateParams', 'tests', function($stateParams, tests) {
            return tests.get($stateParams.id);
          }]
        }
      })
```

The view is rendered:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/tests.html">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>{{test.name}} | Results</h1>
  </div>


  <div ng-repeat="result in test.results">
     <h4>{{result.timestamp}} | <span ng-class="result.passed"}">{{result.passed}}</span></h4>
     <h5>Output:</h5>
     <p style="white-space: pre;">{{result.output}}</p> <!--white-space:pre to preserve formatting (ie \n's)-->
     <h5 style="color:red";>Errors:</h5>
     <p style="white-space: pre;">{{result.error}}</p>
  </div>

<!-- ... -->
```

All of this works well enough except that I can't get the view to update without manually refreshing the page. For now I am just trying to create a similar timer in the controller which reloads the test parameter on a schedule. (ie for now it doesnt matter if the update occurs exactly when the new result is added, I just want the view to update periodically with new tests.) The closest I've gotten seems to be something like:

```
angular.module('syntinel')
  .controller('TestsCtrl', [
  '$scope',
  'tests',
  'test',
  'auth',
  '$interval',
  function($scope, tests, test, auth, $interval){
    $scope.test = test;
    $scope.isLoggedIn = auth.isLoggedIn;

    $scope.runTest = function(){
      tests.run(test);
    };

    // How to get scope to refresh?
    $interval( function(){ 
        $scope.test = tests.get(test._id); 
     }, 3000);


  }]);
```

So I'm trying to just do a new get request to retrieve the latest data from the db, which should contain any newly added 'results'. I don't get any errors, but the current list of results being display goes away and I have no data being displayed in the view once this code runs.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: looks like `tests.get()` is a `promise`, did you try `tests.get(test._id).then(functuion(test) { $scope.test = test });`

Comment: Yep, that does the trick! Thanks. This does lead to a follow up question though.. Now when this promise is fulfilled, the page 'refreshes' and I get new results added to the view, however the view jumps to the top of the page. Is there a way to have it maintain the user's location on the page?

Comment: Nice!, and for keeping scroll position check [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33724014/how-to-retain-the-scroll-position-of-ng-repeat-in-angularjs-when-removing-an-ite)