# Angularjs: ng-click that changes an ng-repeat scrolls the page to top but I don't want it

Tags: angularjs, scroll, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I have this code:

```
<ul class="tab">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" ng-class="{ active: categoria == 1 }" ng-click="cambiaCategoria(1)">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" ng-class="{ active: categoria == 2 }" ng-click="cambiaCategoria(2)">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" ng-class="{ active: categoria == 3 }" ng-click="cambiaCategoria(3)">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="main_list cta tab-content" body-scroll="true" id="cta" z-infinite-scroll="loadEventi">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in giornieventi" ng-cloak>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code is in the middle of the page. The problem is that when I click on one of link, the function "cambiaCategoria" changes the "giornieventi" variable (in the repeater) and the page scrolls to top.
I want to not scroll the page to top. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried removing href from `a` tag ?

Comment: Tried, not working :(

Comment: any console error? post your `cambiaCategoria` function

Comment: `$scope.cambiaCategoria = function(id) {
  $scope.paginazione  = 0;
  $scope.categoria    = id;
  $scope.giornieventi = {};
  $scope.loadEventi();
    }`

Comment: This might solve your problem I reckon [How to retain scroll position of ng-repeat in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23736647/how-to-retain-scroll-position-of-ng-repeat-in-angularjs)

Comment: I tried either without success