# Scroll to id in pages with datatables doesn't work

Tags: jquery, datatables

Here http://files.giro54.net/fede/table-anchor/link-src.html I have a page with two links, the first one goes to a page with five tables generated by datatables plugin, and the second link to a plain simple static html also with five tables. Both links are pointing to the 5th table in the destination pages. The second link works as expected: it scrolls to the 5th table on the static html. But The first link doesn't scroll at all.

I spent a couple of hours trying to solve this. :(
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

## Why is this happening?

The scrolling is automatic for the static html page by default (this could potentially be a browser issue). There are several fixes to this issue, I will let you decide which is the most appropriate to solve the problem:

## How can I solve this?

Just as this problem for the JQuery has not solved itself by default, you can do it dynamically (like everything else we can do with JS/JQ):

[1.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page) Include the following in your $document.ready:

```
$window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

[2.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773921/how-to-automatically-scroll-down-a-html-page) Grab the element you want, and put it into the viewport:

```
$document.getElementById( 'bottom' ).scrollIntoView();
```

As said, there are several ways of solving this, and the problem lies in the JQuery vs. static and how it is being served to the browser of choice, these **fine tuning parameters** are set to default in some browsers and not in others.

PS: Word to the wise, don't post links to your site, just images and code snippets. This may hinder your answers from others in the future.

Comment: thanks for the answer @bmc.
I tried the jquery option but now i'm getting the alert "$window is not defined" in the console.

Comment: I am not sure how you are trying to use $window, but the syntax looks alot [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655273/jquery-window-scrolltop-but-no-window-scrollbottom), similar to the `$(document).ready` synax.

Comment: sorry, i don't have too much jQuery skills.

`$(document).ready(function() {
$window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
});`

Comment: i still have this issue. $window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight); throws "Uncaught ReferenceError: $window is not defined" inside $document.ready. I updated the link test html.

Comment: Potentially you could try to Jquery equivalent: $(window).scrollTo( ... )

Comment: i'm trying with your jquery code, now it says "$(...).scrollTo is not a function".

Comment: No ko, the scrollTo what meant to get you started in the right direction with a google search by the ...notation. Try looking up the function and seeing what arguments it needs.