# how to move the screen without a click to the bottom of the page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a website using JavaScript. I need to programm it in such a way, that when you open the website, you directly get to the bottom of the page (without clicking anything). That means, the page moves itself automatically downwards. 
How can I get this done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll Automatically to the Bottom of the Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page)

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.scrollTo()` function

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good answer: 
[how to automatically scroll down a html page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773921/how-to-automatically-scroll-down-a-html-page)

Including a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/DG8yR/

Script:

```
function top() {
    document.getElementById( 'top' ).scrollIntoView();    
};

function bottom() {
    document.getElementById( 'bottom' ).scrollIntoView();
    window.setTimeout( function () { top(); }, 2000 );
};

bottom();
```

Html:

```
<div id="top">top</div>
<div id="bottom">bottom</div>
```

CSS:

```
#top {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 3000px;
}

#bottom {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

- Call This function on a component or page that you want the particular behaviour. This function will scroll to the bottom of the page. There **won't** be any `scrolling effect` without the css for smooth scroll. I have shown how to specify the `css` for the scrolling effect below, incase you require the scroll behaviour.

  ```
  function scrollToPageBottom() {
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
  }
  ```
- If you require the scroll behaviour:
  Here, I'm specifying the scroll behaviour on the root itself. You can target specific containers as per your requirement

  ```
  *{
     scroll-behavior: smooth;
   }
  ```

> P.S:  This question has many answers already posted but I am sharing
> this because no one talks about the css scroll behaviour which some
> users may require. This answer is specific to the question where the
> OP wants to scroll to the bottom of the page without any user action
> when a page or component is opened or rendered but also specifyiuing the CSS for scroll behaviour if a user requires it.