# How to automatically scroll to the next HTML tag after set time, and repeat forever

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a rather simple website for a digital signage display. I have several full page (fullscreen) containers each labeled with a class name such as "Intro", "Services", "Projects", etc. I want to be able to have the website automatically scroll from the intro "page" to the next services page after a set amount of time, and then do the same for projects. Once I've reached the projects page and have been on it for a set time, then I want to automatically scroll back up to the top and start again. I'm fine with this solution being either in HTML somehow, or by using Javascript. If you need any code snippets, more info, or even a link to my test website please let me know. I found a [live preview](http://demo.paul-themes.com/#jonny_html) of a similar design to my website, if you need a better idea on what I have, but this one doesn't auto scroll either.

Comment: Hello, Have you tried with a carousell ?

Comment: @Csharls Thanks to your suggestion I went ahead and implemented a nice solution using PagePiling.js, feel free to see my own answer for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and took a different route, and implemented [PagePiling.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/pagePiling.js/) and set each of my "pages" as an anchor spot. From there, I made sure that `loopBottom: true` and then implemented a function that I call on page load that goes like this

```
function pageScroll() {
$.fn.pagepiling.moveSectionDown();
scrolldelay = setTimeout(pageScroll,10000); }
```

This is essentially exactly what I was looking for, thanks to @Csharls for suggesting using a carousell, as I would have never thought about doing this without that suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to take a look at this question, it has the automatic scroll and also a timer to scroll back up, hope it works! [how to automatically scroll down a html page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773921/how-to-automatically-scroll-down-a-html-page)