# Unable to scroll to bottom of div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried all the ways available on the net, yet couldn't scroll to the bottom of div when an element is clicked.

But I can determine the bottom when the div is scrolled manually. Help me to automatically scroll to the bottom of div instead, please.

> determines the bottom of div when scrolled

```
$(".ckit-container__bd").on('scroll', function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
        alert('bottom');
    }
});
```

> Attempts to scroll to the bottom automatically:

1) `$('.ckit-container__bd').scrollTop($('.ckit-container__bd').offset().top);`

2)

```
 $(".ckit-container__bd").animate({
    scrollTop: $('.ckit-container__bd')[0].scrollHeight - $('.ckit-container__bd')[0].clientHeight
 }, 1000);
```

3)

```
var objDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("ckit-container__bd");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

DOM STRUCTURE:

[image]

Comment: You may be able to get an idea from this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773405/how-to-auto-scroll-to-target-div-with-jquery)

Comment: show your html code

Comment: @TheMechanic, I added DOM structure as image in my post above..note that, div with this class has scrollbar .ckit-container__bd and I need to get to the bottom of this div.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){
  
  var $sc = $("#scrollable"); // Store your element reference

  $sc.stop().animate({
     scrollTop: $sc[0].scrollHeight - $sc[0].clientHeight
  }, 800);
  
});
```

```css
#scrollable{height:150px; width:200px; overflow:auto;}
p{height:500px; border:2px dashed #000;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>SCROLL TO BOTTOM</button>
<div id="scrollable">
<p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I got this fixed by changing the scrollTopvalue from 0 to 20000.

```
$('.ckit-container__bd').animate({scrollTop: 20000}, 2000);
```

Comment: `20000` is all but a nice fix :)

Answer (score -2):

Scroll will work in display window.

A element like div is not display window, so even the bottom position is valid, the scroll is invalid.

Maybe you can try think like this - scroll means element move. A element[div] as a wrap and style attribute[overflow:hidden], a element[div] in it and move the inner element[div] to implement the function scroll.

Hope some help for you.

Comment: I already have inner element which is .ckit-container__bd and wrapper..but it doesn't get to the bottom. Only maybe the first few times it scrolled automatically but after that it doesn't