# Auto scroll sections web site

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to autoscroll through the sections, but it only works in s1 and s3. According to how I think the code should work, s3 should jump to s2, but it jumps to s1 instead. wheel events do get picked up, I checked with alert(); All other lines of code do get executed. It is the scrollTop does not work, probably because of the layout, but I can not spot the problem. I would appreciate any clues. Thank you!

```
<div class="header" id="main">
    <div class="menu.container" >
        <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer;margin-right: 2vh;color: 
whitesmoke;" onclick="openOffcanvas();openNav3()">&#9776; </span>         
    </div>
</div>

<div class="therest" >
    <div id="myCanvasNav" class="overlay3" onclick="closeOffcanvas()" 
style="width: 0%; opacity: 0;"></div>
    <section  id="s1" class="section">  
        <div  class="content">
            <h1>CompanyX Goes All in With React Native</h1>
            <h2>Starting in 2018, CompanyX Engine will support React Native.
</h2>
            <img src="5.jpg" />

        </div>    
    </section>
    <section id="s2">  
         <div  class="content">

        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="s3" style="background-color: aqua">  
        <div  class="content">

        </div>
     </section>


 </div>
 <script id="jsbin-javascript">
 var headerHight = $("main").height();   
var doWheel = true;    
document.getElementById("s1").addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(!doWheel) return;
    doWheel = false;

    $('div.therest').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#s2").offset().top - headerHight
    }, 600);

    setTimeout(turnWheelBackOn,1000);


});
function turnWheelBackOn() { doWheel = true; }

document.getElementById("s2").addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    if(!doWheel) return;
    doWheel = false;

    $('div.therest').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#s3").offset().top - headerHight
    }, 600);

    setTimeout(turnWheelBackOn, 1000);

});
document.getElementById("s3").addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    if(!doWheel) return;
    doWheel = false;

    $('div.therest').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#s2").offset().top - headerHight
    }, 600);

    setTimeout(turnWheelBackOn, 1000);

});

</script>
```

Comment: This link may help you: [Autoscroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773405/how-to-auto-scroll-to-target-div-with-jquery)

Comment: Kannan K, not quite :( I do not want to hardcode scrolling distances.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your css setting, but normally we use the following code to force window scroll to the element. Make sure use html and body to animate scroll function. You can replace the following code to your event.

```
$("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $("#s2").offset().top - $(".header").height() //Base on your stcky header, you need to minus the header height
},1000 /*scroll in ms*/);
```

**Edit: Minus Header Height for you**

You must not animate the scrolling on a div, it should not work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the header is sticky though, so I have to apply scrollTop to a scrollable part of the html. I figured that scrolling works, it is just the .offset().top gives the wrong value. ???

Comment: It is a correct value. I updated for you. scrollTop may not work on div, but body/ html.

Comment: Because of a sticky header, HTML/body is not a scrollable element, therefor ScrollTop does not work on it. The biggest scrollable div is position: absolute, that is why .offset().top does not return a proper value. I will share a solution if I fix it. Thank you