# Make a navigation from footer to header on my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I want to create a website with **reversed navigation**.

You start **from footer** and you climb **to header** at the end of the website.

If it's possible I would only use CSS and Javascript (jQuery)

[image: Navigation example]

My code structure :

```
<body>
    <div class="end"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="start"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question now?

Comment: So basically a Landingpage (Onepage), where you start at the bottom of the page, when you visit it and have to scroll upwards?

Comment: With flexbox and order, you can put the markup where you want and change the order

Comment: yes that's it !

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @StephanT. I already created my elements and I try to make a navigation using flexbox

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773405/how-to-auto-scroll-to-target-div-with-jquery     Look at this question, that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

To scroll to the bottom of the page:

```
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.offsetHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) parent you can change the order of the elements or use `column-reverse` [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ssgdoc5o/) and as @jcubic said in his answer use the `window.scrollTo(0, document.body.offsetHeight);` so once the page loads it will be at the body at the bottom. Hope this helps.

```js
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.offsetHeight);
```

```css
html,body{margin: 0;}
.flex{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
header{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #a9a9a9;
  align-items: center;
}

nav{
  width: 30%;
}

nav ul{
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 0;
  
 
}

nav ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

footer{
  background-color: #a9a9a9;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <header>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/88x88" alt="">
  </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
   <section>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <h1>Content</h1>
  </section>
  <footer>
    footer content
  </footer>

</div>
```